# Creating an object that populates dynamically

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
var deletedRows = [];

function DeleteRow(el) {
    deletedRows.push({
        entityid: el.parent().attr('entityid'),
        itemid: el.attr('itemid')
    });
}
```

How do I simplify this collection so that there won't be duplicate `entityid`'s. So the key needs to be `entityid`, and the value needs to be a list of `itemid`'s. Ie. "if this entityid already exists, add the itemid to it"

I've thought of doing an associative array with the values as a delimited lists of itemids, but I really want to find a cleaner way to do this. Any ideas greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood what you mean. If I did, with this method you will get an array with every itemID for each entityid.

```
var deletedRows = {};

function DeleteRow(el) {
  var ID = el.parent().attr('entityid');
  var itemID = el.attr('itemid');

  if(deletedRow[ID] === undefined)
    deleteRow[ID] = [];
  deletedRows.push(itemID);
}
```

result would be like :

```
deletedRows = 
{ 
    "ID1" = ["itemID1", "itemID2"],
    "ID2" = ["itemID3"]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

using array:

```
var deletedRows = [];

function DeleteRow(el) {
    var entityid = el.parent().attr('entityid');
    var itemid = el.attr('itemid');
    for (var i=0; i<deletedRows.length; ++i) {
        if (deletedRows[i].entityid == entityid) {
            if (deletedRows[i].itemid instanceof Array) {
                deletedRows[i].itemid.push(itemid);
            } else {
                var olditem = deletedRows[i].itemid;
                deletedRows[i] = [olditem, itemid];
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    deletedRows.push({
        entityid: entityid,
        itemid: itemid
    });
}
```